# Spring Boot: Return Matching Order in Json Format

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this controller method that find a matching order within a json Array of Object and return `true` or `false` depending if the order exists or not. Please see method below:

```
@GetMapping(value="/lok/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
public String getBasicAut(OrdersList ordersList, @PathVariable("id") String id){
    List<Order> olst = basicAuth.orderDetails(ordersList).getBody().getOrders();
    int orderFound = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < olst.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(olst.get(i).getId());
        Long order_id = Long.parseLong(id);
        if(olst.get(i).getId() == order_id){
            orderFound = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            orderFound = 0;
        }
    }
    if(orderFound == 1){
        return "Order found!";
    } else {
        return "Order not found!";
    }
}
```

The array of objects list I search through is structured as in:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2073128511111,
    "email": "email1@gmail.com",
    "number": "5543"
  },
  {
    "id": 2073128511112,
    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
    "number": "5542"
  },
  {
    "id": 2073128511113,
    "email": "email@3@gmail.com",
    "number": "5541"
  }

]
```

What I am trying to do here is once I feed my method an id of 2073128511113 - for example - I would like to get the object information in an object instead of a string of rather it is found or not. The desired output would be - for the example id above:

```
  {
    "id": 2073128511113,
    "email": "email@3@gmail.com",
    "number": "5541"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just directly return an Order object in your method :

public Order getBasicAut

And return the Order object which match your ID, so instead of a for loop with int do directly

for (Order order : olst){ if(order.getId() == myId){ return order; } }

or better if you use Java > 8 use stream to filter in your ID and return your Order object